# Channel Ratings: PHP Errors in Control Panel

Tags: devdemon, channel-ratings

I'm getting these PHP errors when I visit Channel Ratings in the control panel:

Ratings, Likes, and Fields Tabs:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
> conversion Filename: libraries/Ratings_helper.php Line Number: 164

Settings Tab:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
> conversion Filename: libraries/Ratings_helper.php Line Number: 164
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
> conversion Filename: libraries/Ratings_helper.php Line Number: 164
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
> conversion Filename: libraries/Ratings_helper.php Line Number: 164

- EE 2.9
- Channel Ratings 4.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if the channel_ratings_router is present in exp_actions?

If not, run these SQL queries to insert them

```
INSERT INTO exp_actions (method, class) values('channel_ratings_router', 'Channel_ratings');
INSERT INTO exp_actions (method, class) values('insert_rating', 'Channel_ratings');
INSERT INTO exp_actions (method, class) values('insert_like', 'Channel_ratings');
INSERT INTO exp_actions (method, class) values('bayesian', 'Channel_ratings');
```

[image]

Comment: I actually don't see any actions with the `Channel_ratings` class at all.

Comment: Thats the issue. If you just installed Channel Ratings i would try reinstalling. You need those actions in the exp_actions table.

Comment: I didn't just install Channel Ratings, though. I can't reinstall because I'll lose my data. Is there a script I can use to add those table rows to `exp_actions`?

Comment: I updated my answer with some sql queries

Comment: Cleared it right up. Thanks! Wonder how those rows got deleted...